# Hyperledger fabric installation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have windows 7 machine and RHEL 6.0.

Can we install hyperledger fabric on Windowa 7 and RHEL 6.0 without using vagrant and docker.? If yea, please describe the steps.

Answer (score 3):

Hyperledger Fabric does not deliver a complete set of binaries for all operating systems. There are native binaries for the various tools (`configtxgen`, `cryptogen`, `configtxlator` and `peer`) available for Windows, MacOSX, and Linux (for X86, ppc and s390 architectures). There are published Docker images for Ubuntu. Building Centos/RHEL images or binaries should be a straight-forward process, but is not presently a tested/supported configuration. The Node and Java SDKs should run just about anywhere.

It should also be noted that you cannot run without Docker, as chaincode is run in independent containers, managed by the peer. Hence, trying to avoid use of Docker is really a forgone conclusion - you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

No.
Here are two walk throughs on how to do it.

https://developer.ibm.com/opentech/2016/07/21/running-hyperledger-fabric-natively-on-windows/

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev-setup/devenv.html

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric 1.0.0 requires RHEL 7.3 or CentOS 7.3, gRPC has a dependency on the latest and greatest gnu C libraries.

Will not work on RHEL 6.0 !